# Unpermitted parameters in Rails strong params from related Model on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, strong-parameters

I'm using a form in Rails to create an instance of one Model and create a join table to another model on create. In my `Accounts` controller, after verifying the new instance of `Account` has been created, I create a new join table based on checkboxes chosen in the form from another model.

Here is my code:

Models:

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :account_authorizations
    has_many :authorizations, through: :account_authorizations
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :authorizations
end
```

```
class Authorization < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :account_authorizations
    has_many :accounts, through: :account_authorizations
end
```

```
class AccountAuthorization < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :account 
    belongs_to :authorization 
end
```

My `Accounts` controller:

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_account, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @accounts = Account.all

  end

  def show 
  end

  def new 
     @authorizations = Authorization.all
  end

  def create 
    byebug 
    @account = Account.new(account_params) 
    if @account.save 
      authorization_ids = params.permit![:authorization][:ids]
      authorization_ids.each do |auth_id| 
      AccountAuthorization.create(authorization_id: auth_id, account_id: params[:id]) if !auth_id.empty?
      end
      flash[:notice] = "Account created sucsessfully"
      redirect_to account_path(@account) 
    else    
      flash[:error] = @item.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
      render :new 
    end
  end

  def edit   
  end

  def update
     @account = Account.update(account_params) 
    if @account.valid?
      flash[:notice] = "Account created sucsessfully"
      redirect_to accounts_path(@account) 
    else    
      flash[:error] = @item.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
      render :edit 
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @account.delete
    redirect_to accounts_path
  end



private 

def find_account 
  @account = Account.find(params[:id])
end

def account_params
    params.permit(
      :account_name,
      :account_address_line1,
      :account_address_line2,
      :account_city,
      :account_state,
      :account_zipcode,
      :account_ppu,
      :account_notes,
      :contact_first_name,
      :contact_last_name,
      :contact_phone,
      :contact_email
    )
  end

end
```

I've tried using .permit! on params but this does not allow the the ids from `Authorization` to pass into a new join instance of `AccountAuthorization`.

The attributes that don't pass are:

```
Unpermitted parameters: :authenticity_token, :authorization, :commit
```

I've also tried putting those in the permit hash in the strong_params method.

** UPDATE **

My Views page with `form`:

```
<% states = [ 'AL', 'AK', 'AS', 'AZ', 'AR', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DC', 'DE', 'DC', 'FL', 'GA', 'HI', 'ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'IA', 'KS', 'KY', 'LA', 'ME', 'MH', 'MD', 'MA', 'MI', 'MN', 'MS', 'MO', 'MT', 'NE', 'NV', 'NH', 'NJ', 'NM', 'NY', 'NC', 'ND', 'MP', 'OH', 'OK', 'OR', 'PA' 'RI', 'SC', 'SD', 'TN', 'TX', 'UT', 'VT' 'VA', 'WA', 'WV', 'WI', 'WY'] %>
<% ppu = ['Employment', 'Insurance', 'Law Enforement'] %>

<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-lg-16">
        <h3>Create New Account</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-lg-16">

            <%= form_with(url: accounts_path, model: @account, local: true) do |f| %>

            <%= f.text_field :account_name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Account Name" %>
            <%= f.text_field :account_address_line1, class: "form-control", placeholder: "address line 1" %>
            <%= f.text_field :account_address_line2, class: "form-control", placeholder: "address line 2" %>
            <%= f.text_field :account_city, class: "form-control", placeholder: "account city" %>
            <%= f.select :account_state, options_for_select(states), { :prompt => true }, class: "form-control", include_blank: true, placeholder: "state" %>
            <%= f.text_field :account_zipcode, class: "form-control", placeholder: "account zipcode" %>
            <%= f.text_field :contact_first_name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "contact first name" %>
            <%= f.text_field :contact_last_name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "contact last name" %>
            <%= f.text_field :contact_phone, class: "form-control", placeholder: "conact phone" %>
            <%= f.text_field :contact_email, class: "form-control", placeholder: "contact email" %>
            <%= f.select :account_ppu, options_for_select(ppu), { :prompt => true }, class: "form-control", include_blank: true, placeholder: "ppu" %>
            <%= f.text_area :account_notes, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Notes..." %>

            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap">
             <%= f.fields_for :authorization do |auth| %>
            <div class="order-3 p-2 bd-highlight">
                <%= auth.collection_check_boxes :ids, Authorization.all, :id, :auth_name %>
            </div>
            <% end %>
             </div>
            <%= f.submit "Create", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
            <% end %>



    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the form, or at least the code that you're using to select the authorization_ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to manually create join table records.

For every `has_many` and `has_many_and_belongs_to_many` association Rails creates a `_ids` setter that takes an array of ids. Rails will automatically create/delete join table rows from the input.

This mates up perfectly with the [collection helpers](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.7/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html).

app/views/accounts/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: account, local: true) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :account_name %>
     <%= f.text_field :account_name %>
  </div>
  # ... more inputs

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :authorization_ids, 'Authorizations' %>
    <%= f.collection_checkboxes :authorization_ids, 
                                Authorization.all, # the collection 
                                :id, # value method
                                :name # label method
    %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  <div>
<% end %>
```

app/views/accounts/new.html.erb

```
<%= render partial: 'form', account: @account %>
```

accounts/edit.html.erb

```
<%= render partial: 'form', account: @account %>
```

app/controllers/accounts_controller.rb

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_account, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # ...

  def create 
    @account = Account.new(account_params) 
    if @account.save 
      flash[:notice] = "Account created sucsessfully"
      redirect_to @account 
    else 
      # render :new does not redirect so you need to use flash.now
      # to display the flash message in this request
      flash.now[:error] = @item.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
      render :new 
    end
  end

  def edit   
  end

  # This is how you update a resource.
  def update
    # don't check .valid? - it just tells you if the validations passed
    # not if the actual DB update query was a successes
    if @account.update(account_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Account updated successfully"
      redirect_to @account
    else    
      flash.now[:error] = @item.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
      render :edit 
    end
  end

  # ...

  private 

  def account_params
    params.require(:account).permit(
      :account_name,
      :account_address_line1,
      :account_address_line2,
      :account_city,
      :account_state,
      :account_zipcode,
      :account_ppu,
      :account_notes,
      :contact_first_name,
      :contact_last_name,
      :contact_phone,
      :contact_email,
      account_ids: []
    )
  end
end
```

Since this slices out the key `:account` from the params hash you won't get the unpermitted parameters error. `authenticity_token` is the Rails CSRF protection token and `commit` is the value of the submit button which was clicked to submit the form. These should not be whitelisted or sent to your model

You whitelist the an array of authorization ids by passing a keyword argument (`account_ids: []`) to `.permit` with an empty array as the value. Since this is a keyword argument it must come after the list of positional arguments.

You also don't need `accepts_nested_attributes_for` unless you're doing something more advanced then just selecting existing records. But you're not quite ready for `accepts_nested_attributes_for`until you have got the basics of doing CRUD down.

Comment: This is so close and I learned so much from your reply. I still get `ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: account)` when I require `(:account)`.

Comment: That's weird. Have you looked at the incoming parameters in the log?

Comment: This is really unexpected and indicates that something is really broken in your app. You would really need to start debugging by look at the rendered form.  The name attribute of the inputs should look like 'name="account[account_name]"' .  You can also check the network tab in your browser and see the raw request body.

Comment: If the form/request looks as expected then something in your app is transforming the parameters. Does this only happens for this route or for all your routes?

Comment: Here are the params passed to controller: https://codeshare.io/5vlM8l

Comment: I had to do this as a temporary fix: `new_params = params
  params = ActionController::Parameters.new(account: new_params) 
    params.require(:account).permit( ......`

Answer (score 1):

What I normally do is this (the require (:account) is very important):

```
def account_params
 params.require(:account).permit(
  :account_name,
  # Rest of the params you want to permit...
  authorization_ids: []
 )
end
```

This will allow you to do a regular save in the controller action.

```
def create 
 @account = Account.new(account_params) 
 if @account.save 
  flash[:notice] = "Account created successfully"
  redirect_to account_path(@account) 
 else    
  flash[:error] = @item.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
  render :new 
 end
end
```

And in the form If you're displaying them as checkboxes.

```
<% Authorization.all.each do |authorization| %>
 <%= check_box_tag 'account[authorization_ids][]', authorization.id, @account.authorizations.include?(authorization), id: dom_id(authorization), type: "checkbox" %>
<% end %>
```

That will iterate through all the authorization records and display it on the screen and if you select them they will be stored in the authorization_ids params, and rails is smart enough to accept those params and create the join associations in that table.

Btw this is using simple form so the code should be modified a bit to get the desired inputs

Comment: You were half way there and then you fell flat on your face in the form. Just use the collection helpers instead of an unreadable 300 character line.

Comment: Yes you're right, it has been a while since I have used rails views, and even more without the usage of simple form.

Comment: I ran into an issue with `params.require(:account)`. I returned an error saying it was 'nil'.